# How to implement promise with custom function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, promise

I am trying to learn how to use promise.

**What triggers the event and update the page**

I use this below to trigger my event and update the page;

```
$("body").on("change", "input, select", function () {
    var field_id = ($(this).attr("id"));
    var container = ['#' + field_id + "_ck", '#' + field_id + '_err'];
    var data_type = ($(this).attr("data-type"));
    var value = document.getElementById(field_id).value;
    var data = validateInput(field_id, data_type, value);

    if (data[0] == 'true') {
        $(container[1]).addClass("pass_f");
        $(container[1]).html(data[2]);
        $(container[0]).html(data[1]);
    }else {
        $(container[1]).removeClass("pass_f");
        $(container[1]).addClass("err_f");
        $(container[1]).html(data[2]);
        $(container[0]).html(data[1]);
    }
});
```

**What validateInput() does**

The validateInput function is returning the data array for the user to correct the information and his as follow;

```
function validateInput(field_id,data_type,value){
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
var c = 2;
var data = [];
    if (data_type == 'username'){
       n = value.length;
       if(n < 5 | n > 15){
         data[a] = "false";
         data[b] = "some html";
         data[c]  = "The error msg regarding this field length";
         return data;
        }
     // the code below would fit here
}
```

**Now what my problem is**

This db_check function is run after the page updage

```
function db_check(field_id, data_type, value, callbackFn) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-php.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'db_check': 'true', 'field_id': field_id, 'value': value, 'data_type': data_type },
            success: function (data2, status) {
                callbackFn(data2);
               // data2 is true or false
            },
          // in case of error
            }
        });         
    };
```

**And then when i use this db_check function**

```
 db_check(field_id, data_type, value, function callbackFn(data2){                                                              
        if (data2 == 'false') {
            data[a] = "false";
            data[b] = "some html";
            data[c] = "its not ok";
            return data;
        }
        else if (data2 == 'true') {
            data[a] = "true";
            data[b] = "some html";
            data[c] = "Its ok.";
            return data;
        }      
   });
```

**How should I implement promise in my code**

The data array does get filled with the right values only after the page is updated. So I wonder where does the promise have to be?

Would it have to go with validateInput instead? like;

I am so lost in all this and would really appreciate a few hint to at least understand how to use promise

**Please note**

all data returned by these function are already json arrays. I have noticed that on all documentation they use json witch is already implemented in my code

Thank you!

Comment: The issue here is that your code will not wait for the success function to return from the ajax request to do the `callbackFn(data2)`. You need to look into `$.deferred()` and `$.promise()` objects.

Comment: Thank you will look into it